# How to analyze repeated measures data that has been subsequently rated by coders

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, agreement-statistics

My question is this: if you have independent coders rate statements that subjects in the original experiment gave, and there were two statements per subject, and you wanted to examine the difference between the repeated factor by coder, do you need to take into account the repeated (or dependent) nature of the original data? Would one use a mixed model?

So let's say I have 50 subjects in the original study. Each subject made two different statements (to a male and to a female), so 'gender' is a repeated factor, and in total there are 100 statements (2 statements made by each subject). I then want 3 different coders to rate each of these 100 statements for 'anxiety'.
And I want to look at whether there is more anxiety in statements made to women vs men by the original subjects.

I have set up the data in long format, so that I have a column for gender, a column for subject ID, and then have averaged the coders's ratings on anxiety into one dependent measure.

In this case, I can't just do a simple t-test to get a gender difference in anxiety, right? I likely need to account for the repeated nature of the data, but not sure exactly how to do that. Do I account for the repeated nature of the coder's answers (e.g. that they rated each of the 100 statements, and for both males and females), or do I just account for the subject repeated factor of gender, and use subject ID as a repeated factor?

I have been looking at this in a mixed model, and am wondering if maybe I have to nest some variables in order accurately portray the data. Any insights would be welcomed as for some reason I can't wrap my head around this. Am I over thinking it?

Comment: If you're already averaged the coders ratings, is there a reason you can't use a paired T-test for the male vs. female ratings that come from the same participant?

Comment: Well three were only 3 coders and they rated about 100 statements (50 male and 50 female) so would I just take the averages of those statements for each gender and then do a paired t-test? Don't I need to account for the three coders somehow?